# SourceKitService Crash in Xcode 7.3 with Dictionaries in for loop

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, dictionary

Maybe this has been stated before as I have already seen but it seems I couldn't find the correct answer for me. I have an array which consists of dictionaries. I am using swift 2.2 and I am trying to access those dictionaries with a "for" loop. But when I am trying to access them I get the SourceKitService crash. Following is my code:

```
    for index in productArray{
        var Dict = index["id"]
    }
```

When I am typing and get to the point: `index["` I get the error and xcode crashes. I am using other dictionaries inside my project but they are working fine. Maybe I have something wrong in my code. I am not sure.

> productArray is a NSMutableArray.

I created the productArray by adding with the following method dictionaries:

```
productArray.addObject(dictionary)
```

This is an example of the productArray array.

```
(
 { id = 1; price = "2.00"; "product_name" = "A"; },
 { id = 2; price = "2.00"; "product_name" = "B"; }
)
```

I also tried the following:

```
                for index in 1...productArray.count{
                var dict = productArray.objectAtIndex(index)
                print(dict[
            }
```

But once again when I reach to this point it crashes. When I try to put "" it crashes.

If anyone could help it would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: If your `productArray` *really* is an array of dictionaries, then your code works. Please [edit] your question and show us a print of `productArray` (or at least what type Xcode says it is).

Answer (score -1):

I solved the problem by adding the following in the back of the initialization of the dict.

First I had:

```
var dict = productArray.objectAtIndex(index)
```

Then:

```
var dict = productArray.objectAtIndex(index) as! [String:String]
```

This solved my problem and works fine.

Comment: The solution to my problem was what I have found. The question was related to the specific way of code structure. It would not be an answer to my question if I had to change my whole code into something else. Thank you.

Comment: I have upvoted it! It was already upvoted from the beginning since you answered.